# How to uninstall dotnetcli from command line

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, macos-catalina, dotnetcorecli

Im using the formula described here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?tabs=macos) to uninstall dotnet core sdk from macos. I followed the steps and after finishing and verifying there is not an sdk nor a runtime, the command dotnet is still valid in the terminal and is referring that is valid at hosting. Any ideas around how to remove all the sdk, cli from my laptop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove **all** versions and components of .NET Core, just delete the main `dotnet` directory:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet
```